# Как отправить данные на сервер js и потом обработать их?

Tags: javascript, java, клиент-сервер

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Хочу отправить данные на сервер с помощью js, после чего получить эти данные на сервере. Как отправить я, вроде, нашел пример (GET):

> ```
> var user = {
>     name: "Tom",
>     age: 23
> };
>
> var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
> function reqReadyStateChange() {
>     if (request.readyState == 4) {
>         var status = request.status;
>         if (status == 200) {
>             document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = request.responseText;
>         }
>     }
> } 
> // строка с параметрами для отправки
> var body = "name=" + user.name + "&age=" + user.age;
> request.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/postdata.php?" + body);
> request.onreadystatechange = reqReadyStateChange;
> request.send();
> ```

Но вот что происходит дальше, где находятся эти данные, и как мне их ловить, я хз.

Обычно я все передавал через hidden компоненты на странице, но сейчас эта ситуация не подходит. Объясните, пожалуйста, джуну.

Comment: вы либо теги перепутали, либо в коде напутали. Запрос вы отправляете не java сервлету, а php странице request.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/postdata.php?" + body);      Хотя конечно можно предположить, что сервлет вы замапили на postdata.php... внесите ясность

Comment: @Виктор я мог вообще всё не правильно понять, поэтому не исключено :) Ясность - я хочу передать данные из js в java код.

Comment: Меняйте "http://localhost:8080/postdata.php" на урл, на который нужно отправить данные

Comment: @Kain Так а дальше что? Как мне получить их в джава коде и в каком виде?

Comment: @Saint, спросите программистов java. Сейчас у вас вопрос по js, а java только в тегах упомянута